# how to aggregate graph using Plotly lib?

Tags: javascript, plotly, aggregate

recently am using plotly in my Angular project .

so am trying to plot data with aggregation ( sum, avg , count .. ) ,

the official doc for plotly shows that it is supported , but am not getting any result .

link of doc : https://plotly.com/javascript/aggregations/

Answer (score 0):

resolved!

In case in the future, this error is encountered:
`groups: []`, in aggregation array, we should pass an array ( content ) not the name of the column of the dataset .